# How to change the order of os.walk() output?

Tags: python, list, sorting, os.walk, python-os

So, apparently `os.walk()` moves through directories "vertically", walking through the input's first directory and all its subdirectories, before moving to the next "top-level" directory.

Code:

```
import os

os.chdir("/home/test")
inp = str(os.getcwd() + "/input")

l = list(os.walk(inp))
```

Output:

```
[('/home/test/input', ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d.txt']),
 ('/home/test/input/a', ['aa'], ['ac.txt', 'ab.txt']),
 ('/home/test/input/a/aa', [], [], 83),
 ('/home/test/input/b', [], ['bb.txt', 'bc.txt', 'ba.txt']),
 ('/home/test/input/c', ['ca'], [], 81),
 ('/home/test/input/c/ca', ['caa'], ['cab.txt']),
 ('/home/test/input/c/ca/caa', [], ['caaa.txt'])]
```

Is there a way to walk "horizontally"?
I would like the output to look like this:

```
[('/home/test/input', ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d.txt']),
 ('/home/test/input/a', ['aa'], ['ac.txt', 'ab.txt']),
 ('/home/test/input/b', [], ['bb.txt', 'bc.txt', 'ba.txt']),
 ('/home/test/input/c', ['ca'], [], 81),
 ('/home/test/input/a/aa', [], [], 83),
 ('/home/test/input/c/ca', ['caa'], ['cab.txt']),
 ('/home/test/input/c/ca/caa', [], ['caaa.txt'])]
```

So that it moves through the directories `a`, `b` and `c`, before going deeper.

**EDIT:** Adding the `topdown=False` parameter doesn't help:

```
[('/home/philipp/test/input/a/aa', [], []),
 ('/home/philipp/test/input/a', ['aa'], ['ac.txt', 'ab.txt']),
 ('/home/philipp/test/input/b', [], ['bb.txt', 'bc.txt', 'ba.txt']),
 ('/home/philipp/test/input/c/ca/caa/x', [], []),
 ('/home/philipp/test/input/c/ca/caa', ['x'], ['caaa.txt']),
 ('/home/philipp/test/input/c/ca', ['caa'], ['cab.txt']),
 ('/home/philipp/test/input/c', ['ca'], []),
 ('/home/philipp/test/input', ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d.txt'])]
```

I could still sort the list with a loop afterwards, but maybe there is a faster and more elegant way to do this.

(The number of files and directories used in the final script will likely be higher than in the example shown above.)

Comment: the usual terms are "depth first" and "breadth first".

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? Isn't this what the `topdown` parameter controls?

Comment: @Barmar Unfortunately not. That just kind of flips it all upside down (see edited post).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I don't think there is a way to do this using one or 2 lines of code. There is a longer way to do this using the `os` module though! You can try this:

```py
import os

def _dir_list(path):
    files = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path)]
    print(str(files) + "\n")
    for f in files:
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, f)):
            _dir_list(os.path.join(path, f))

path = r"C:\PATH"

_dir_list(path)
```

Basically, this gets all the folders in 1 directory, without digging into them. Then, it increments through the files and, for each one, it does the function again, getting the files in THAT directory, essentially doing what you want it to do.

We limit the directory using `os.listdir()`, which returns all the current folders in the form of a list.